# Position a 3D camera directly above or below the target

Tags: webgl, camera, javascript

I'm trying to setup a 3D camera in WebGL. The camera is setup with the help of a lookAt function. The lookAt function takes `cameraTarget`, `cameraPosition` and `up` as as inputs.

The code can be found here: https://codepen.io/Candleout/pen/poxMLPB If the scene looks empty you load the CodePen, simply run the code again.

[image: axes]

How can I position the camera straightly above or below the target?

In the scene, Z (blue) is the vertical axis, while X (red) and Y (green) represents the horizontal plane. I have tried putting the object at `[0, 0, 0]` and giving the camera a position of `[0, 0, distance]`. With a `cameraTarget` of `[0, 0, 0]` (same as the object) I was expecting this would give me a top-down view of the object. However, if I set the camera position to `[0, 0, distance]` the object disappears. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Use a delta like `0.001` in either the X or the Y component of the `cameraposition`. It disappears because you set `up` vector to the Z axis. When the `lookat` function tries to compute the X axis it'll turn out to be 0. Look how lookAt computes the axes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be because of multiple reasons:

first as @gallickgunner said, the up vector which is passed to the `lookAt` function should not be alligned to the view direction! Here you need to pass in the up direction of the camera (not the world). So when having a top down view, up shoud be a vector within the plane x/y.

The next thing why you maybe don't see anything can be, that your object don't lie within the projection matrix near and far clipping planes.

Take a look at [OpenGL tutorial matrices](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-3-matrices/).

Comment: Thank you @Thomas ! I didn't know the upward direction is related to the camera and not the world. Does this mean you need to define a new upward direction every time the perspective changes? Let's say you gradually rotate the camera by adding a transformation to the view matrix. The camera goes from looking straight down, as in the example, to looking straight ahead. At what point do you update the upward direction?

Comment: @Candleout I only update the upward direction when using the `lookAt` function. When applying transformations by multiplying matrices, you don't need the upward direction.

Comment: Okay! Thanks for the clarification. @Thomas